# Remix IDE & Cardano

Tags: ide

Are there currently any plans for a Cardano version of the Remix IDE?

Currently it works for Solidity on Ethereum and Binance Smart Chain and the network is selectable from a drop fown list box. This suggests at least some form of modularity and extensibility.

Comment: Welcome to our new community! This question has 2 close votes (not from me!) so I just thought I'd warn you that these type of questions that are only temporarily valuable may be better for our [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123509/cardano) room.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about the future of Cardano can't be effectively addressed on this site and would be better addressed directly to the Cardano Team on their [forum](https://forum.cardano.org/). This site is not operated by the Cardano organization.

Answer (score 0):

I did not personally hear anything about such plans.

However, I'm voting to close this question as I feel this is good question for Remix developers and might be off-topic for this StackExchange space.